# alphabetically sort an array of inputted words with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, alphabetical

I am new to javascript and jquery. I need help figuring out what is wrong with my code because it is not executing ".sort()" and ".join(", ") during the last steps...

I want the page to have a pop-up box where the user types in a place (inputs are stored in the array) and continues that until they type 'done', and then the page loads their list of places in alphabetical order with commas. I got the first part ok (the prompts and entering text), but my page doesn't load the entered material after entering 'done'. Below is my code:

```
        <div id="outputPlaces"></div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var favPlaces = [];
                var input = prompt("Please enter your favorite place or type done to stop entering places.");
                while (input != 'done') {
                    favPlaces.push(input);
                    input = prompt("Please enter another favorite place or type done to stop entering places.");
                }
                favPlaces.sort();
                $('#outputPlaces').html = favPlaces.join(", ")

            });

        </script>
```

Comment: `$(`…`).html` is a function that you need to call like this: `$('#outputPlaces').html(favPlaces.join(", "))`.

Comment: @Xufox oops, meant to type favPlaces, i fixed it now..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like you had `favWords` instead of `favPlaces`.

`.html(favPlaces.join(", "))`

Comment: This is wrong: `html` is a function with an optional parameter. If it’s missing, it gets the inner HTML, otherwise it _sets_ it. The issue isn’t about `text` vs. `html`, it’s about how to use the function.

Comment: You're right that this is wrong and this is why I shouldn't use the SO mobile app... I'm updating my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Because favWords is not defined. Maybe you mean favPlaces.join(", ") and try changing $('#outputPlaces').html = favPlaces.join(", ") to document.getElementById("outputPlaces").innerHTML = favPlaces.join(", ")